# extra vertical space in edge

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex

i wrote this code to get output without margin spaces.
but i saw there is some extra vertical space between charater A and up edge of pdf file.
1 inch vertical and horizontal extra space is the default margin space in PDFTeX.

[image: output]

is that a bug for plain tex?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `\topskip`:

```tex
\voffset=-1in
\hoffset=-1in
\parindent=0pt
\topskip=0pt

A
\bye
```

---

##### Old Answer

This is the intended behaviour of TeX, although it admittedly seems questionable today.

You can remove the "extra" 1in offset in modern engines, although this will likely confuse any layout-related packages that you load.

[pdfTeX](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdftex/0#page=20):

```tex
\pdfhorigin=0pt
\pdfvorigin=0pt
```

[LuaTeX](https://texdoc.org/serve/luatex/0#page=50):

```tex
\pdfvariable horigin 0pt
\pdfvariable vorigin 0pt
```

Comment: thanks, but no difference.

Comment: @Minoo Whoops, I totally misread the question. See the new edit.